# Button and radio button inside excel CSV after file upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

A excel CSV (comma seperated value) file is uploaded initially. This CSV file is represented as a table format in an html page. Here, I need to add a radio button, button etc,along with the table formatted representation. Is this possible without usage of database?.
Thanks in advance.

```
  function Upload() {
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var table = document.createElement("table");
    var radio = document.createElement("radio");    
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");     
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);


                var cells = rows[i].split(",");

                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                }
            }

            var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
            dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
            dvCSV.appendChild(table);
     dvCSV.appendChild(radio);

        }

        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);

    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
}
```

}

I had created an element 'radio' inside function also appended as a child, but it doesn't displays it. My requirement is that, when each row of CSV file is placed, I need to place a radio and button there.(radio for selecting and button for editing the row element and save file).

Comment: How is that file being uploaded? Did you try something to accomplish such? if so - please provide us what you have tried. Anyway, yes, this can be accomplished without the use of a database, but you need to tell us a bit more.

Comment: you can use filereader https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader to read file directly in browser

Comment: I had included the code that I am using. I need to include buttons inside the function 'Upload()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var radio = document.createElement("radio");
```

means `<radio></radio>`. However, there is no `radio` tag. It's `<input type="radio">`:

```
var radio = document.createElement("input");
radio.type = 'radio';
```

To "group" all radio buttons together, you also need to give them the same name:

```
radio.name = 'radio';
```

And if you say you need a button too, then create one:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'Click me';
```

But most importantly, if you need them for every row, then put them there, and not somewhere else:

```
reader.onload = function(e)
{
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
        for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)
        {
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
        }
        // Here:
        var radio = document.createElement("input");
        radio.type = 'radio';
        radio.name = 'radio';
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = 'Click me';
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.appendChild(radio);
        cell.appendChild(button);
    }
    var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
    dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
    dvCSV.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Siguza. feeling happy with this solution.

Comment: While executing,If there were 5 rows, it shows 6 set of objects, where it should be decremented by one. Also, Is it possible for providing an id to each radio/button separately? Do I use arrays? How to enhance  multiple radio button selection ?

Comment: 1. Are you talking about rows or columns? And define "set of objects". 2. Yes, you can provide a different id for each radio button, but why? 3. Do you use arrays? For what? I suppose you can, but again, why? 4. "Enhance" is an extremely broad term, so unless you want laser cats and dinosaurs, consider asking a specific question. What do you want exactly? You don't go to a carpenter either and just ask them to "improve your chair".

Comment: CSV file contains name and email-id, from each row I need to select each persons randomly. So, to identify each row based on button OR radio 'id' OR is it possible for providing 'id' for columns(name/email)?

Comment: Email-id? Do you mean address? "select each persons randomly" - I don't understand that at all. Example? And no, you cannot provide ids for columns, since in HTML there are no columns, only rows. Apart from that, you can assign an id to every HTML element you wish.

Comment: The first row of csv file is as follows, with name and email address: rambo,rambo@rambo.com. I want to send a mail to that email address by selecting the row with radio button. Is that possible?

Comment: Only with a radio button? No, you'll need more than that. Anyway, that's an entirely different matter, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: How an on-click action can be performed with that radio button?

Comment: googled it, most replies are based on html check-boxes, that means check-box that transfers data using 'on-click' inside <input> tag. Here, the check-boxes inserted on javascript loop, and I  think I am stuck at loop. I just needed to identify each radio button separately.

Comment: @RahulGopi So what is your problem with that?

Comment: If I could identify each radio button separately, on-clicking that radio button I could identify that row, and hence I could print each row value.

Comment: @RahulGopi This conversation is not going anywhere. I'll say "You *can* do that, what's your problem?" Then you say "How do I do it?" Then I say "What have you tried?" Then you give me another three lines of text with highly ambiguous terms and claim it "doesn't work". Ask a new question, show the code you have, make a clear statement about what you want to add, and show any attempts to do so.